# Subgaussianity of the Mixture of Gaussian Random Variables

Tags: probability, statistics, gaussian

Is a mixture distribution of gaussian subgaussian?

We know that if $X$ follows a normal distribution $\mathcal{N} (0, \sigma^2)$, then it is automatically $\sigma$-subgaussian by definition.

Suppose we have a mixture of normal random variables $X_1, X_2$. Then does the mixture of these two also have subgaussianity? Suppose the mixture has distribution $f_x(x)$, then:$$f_X(x) = \alpha f_1(x) + (1-\alpha)f_2(x),$$
where $\alpha$ is the probability assigned to a component.

**Subgaussianity:** Suppose random variable $X$ follows the inequality below: $$\mathbf{\mathbb{E}[e^{\lambda X}]\leq \exp(\lambda^2 \sigma^2)},$$then we say that $X$ is **$\boldsymbol{\sigma}$-subgaussian.**

Comment: Can you define subgaussianity?

Comment: @Thomas Hi Thomas. I have added the definition of sub-gaussianity in the text. Note that it's usually an abuse of notation to say that X is sub-gaussian even when X has non-zero mean. That means we just assume that X is centered here, and so do the component variables.

Comment: So $X_1$ and $X_2$ have the same expectation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $X_1$ and $X_2$ be zero mean and sub-Gaussian.

Let $Z$ be such that $P(Z=1)=\alpha$ and $P(Z=2) = 1-\alpha$, and let $X=\mathbf{1}_{Z=1} X_1 + \mathbf{1}_{Z=2}X_2$. Note that $E[X]=0$ as well.

$$E[e^{\lambda X}] = E[E[e^{\lambda X} \mid Z]]
= \alpha E[e^{\lambda X_1}] + (1-\alpha) E[e^{\lambda X_2}]
\le \alpha e^{\lambda^2 \sigma_1^2/2} + (1-\alpha) e^{\lambda^2 \sigma_2^2/2}
\le e^{\lambda^2 \max\{\sigma_1^2, \sigma_2^2\}/2}.$$

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer here. I just have a minor question here that is in the last step, shouldn't there be a 2 constant before the last expression? I mean both $\alpha$ and $1-\alpha$ are less than 1, then shouldn't there be a 2 before as the result of both inequalities? that is $2\exp{ \lambda^2 \max\{ \sigma_1^2, \sigma_2^2\}/2}$

Comment: Sorry I just made an algera mistake, your solution is absolutely correct.